# Does the 'reproducing kernel formula' for a bounded open set $U$ define an equivalent norm on the Sobolev space $H^1_0(U)$

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, pseudo-differential-operators, micro-local-analysis

We refer to the 'reproducing convolution formula with a kernel' for an open bounded domain $U$ of $R^n$, $n \geq 2$ discussed in the paper of G. Talenti (Annali de Matematica, Dec 1976) on Best constant in Sobolev inequality. This gives $u$ in terms of its gradient $\nabla u$ for a bounded open set $U$. My question is,

**For an appropriate pointwise relation from a subsequence, does the reproducing kernel formula for a bounded open set $U$ define an equivalent norm on the Sobolev space $H^1_0(U)$ ?**

Note that the smooth functions with compact support are dense in $H^1_0(U)$ but not in $H^1(U)$,so the closure in regard of the test space applies on both sides of the kernel formula only for $H^1_0(U)$, while the closure applies to $L^2$ as well.

Note that on a suitable subsequence, pointwise relations hold almost everywhere; in fact, the limits can be considered in $L^p(U)$ when the support vanishes outside $U$, due to integrability of the kernel in $dim.n$ for $n \geq 2$. I also wish to add that the Atiyah-Singer index is zero for $n > 2$.  Interestingly, it is awkward to show membership for both the spaces using the same $H^1$ norm,so the equivalence desired produces different norms.

Since Poincare inequality can be uniformly used for all $L^q(U)$, Hedberg estimates (Lars Inge Hedberg, Proc. AMS (1972) on convolution inequalities) appears to give the estimate for the $L^p$ norm of $\nabla u$ (not $u$), which I wish to confirm.

Note also that participation of the kernel is actually the reason for increased Lebesgue index $p*$

My research interests are applied analysis, PDE, Microlocal Analysis, Infinity Laplacian and Pseudo-differential operators.

Answer (score 1):

(I want to post a potential answer that I have researched over the past months; if this is better placed as a comment, please advise)

With reference to the paper *On certain convolution inequalities* Lars Inge Hedberg, Proc AMS, Vol 36, No.2, Dec 1972, see the pointwise estimate (3) in terms of the Maxmimal function on pp 506 along (1) on pp 505, taking $\alpha = 1$ and replacing $f$ by $grad(f)$.

Now estimate the $p*$-norm over $\mathbb{R}^d,d \geq 2$, using the reproducing formula, noting $p* = (p*-1) + 1$, use Holder estimate for this split. Keeping aside the 'link constants' c, A, the Holder conjugate corresponding to ($p* - 1$) (for the $p*$ power) is estimated using the maximal inequality for $p > 1$ in integration over $\mathbb{R}^d$ by $|\nabla f|^{g(p)}, g(p): n - \frac{n}{p} + 1, 1 < g(p) < p < n;$ note that $p \leftrightarrow g(p)$ for $p$ in
$(1,n)$ is one-one and onto, as can be seen from the graph of $g(p)$. The trajectory $g(p) = n - \frac{n}{p} + 1, p \in (1,n)$ corresponds to the 'limiting case' of the staircase constructed in Charles J Arick's paper, Proc. LMS (1978). As for the standard 'counter examples' to RK compactness at $p*$, with a choice of any $q$ on the trajectory, 'gain' is seen over and above $1 - n/p + n/p* = 0$.

Thus, equivalence of norm is seen and in this norm, identification of $H^1_0(U)$ as a Nuclear space is compact.